# Ansible task to cleanup file backups

Tags: python, linux, ansible, ansible-template

Is there a way to automatically cleanup backup files ansible creates when useing e.g. the `copy` or `template` modules, or to keep the last three backup files for example?

[Ansible file backups from template task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7j7m.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The subject was different (restore a backup file) but you will find some ideas (list files, etc...) to possibly acheive your requirement in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368712/9401096)

Comment: I mean to cleanup Backupfiles which are created by the backup: yes option. Is there an idea for a task to remove the backup files and keep the last three on every run?

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to create my own utility for this as any other way would require extensive Ansible scripting (which in my opinion beats the purpose of Ansible).

https://github.com/moudsen/cleanansiblebackups